# Why does STUFF remove XML?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #Test (id int,Name varchar(30))

insert into #Test values (1,'Ian')
insert into #Test values(1,'Mark')
insert into #Test values(2,'James')
insert into #Test values(3,'Karen')
insert into #Test values(3,'Suzie')
```

and the SQL below:

```
select * from #Test for xml path('')
```

which returns:

```
<id>1</id>
<Name>Ian</Name>
<id>1</id>
<Name>Mark</Name>
<id>2</id>
<Name>James</Name>
<id>3</id>
<Name>Karen</Name>
<id>3</id>
<Name>Suzie</Name>
```

This is what I would expect.  Now see the SQL below:

```
SELECT distinct ID,
STUFF( (select ','+ NAME from #Test as #Test1 where #Test1.id=#Test2.id FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') FROM #Test as #Test2
```

which returns:

```
1   Ian,Mark
2   James
3   Karen,Suzie
```

This is what I want returned.  However, where have the XML elements gone?

Answer (score 2):

You have to compare apples to apples. While it's true that

```
select * from #Test for xml path('')
```

produces something that looks like XML (but technically isn't because it doesn't have a root element), this (what you're actually running)

```
select ',' + name from #Test for xml path('')
```

doesn't. On my machine, it produces the ff string: ",Ian,Mark,James,Karen,Suzie". From there, the stuff function whacks the first comma and you get a list of comma-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `STUFF`, this is only for removing the superfluous first `,`.

The concat removes the XML stuff:

```
','+ NAME
or
NAME + ''
```

Don't ask me why it's working like this, maybe it's documented somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

Inner for xml statement is just for producing concatenating result. Add outer for xml statement:

```
SELECT distinct ID,
    STUFF( (select ','+ NAME 
            from Test as #Test1 
            where #Test1.id=#Test2.id 
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as Names
FROM Test as #Test2
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Output:

```
 <ID>1</ID><Names>Ian,Mark</Names><ID>2</ID><Names>James</Names><ID>3</ID><Names>Karen,Suzie</Names>
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f254/13

Answer (score 1):

> Why does STUFF remove XML?

`STUFF` removes the first comma in the string, it is not responsible for removing the XML element names.

`FOR XML PATH` uses the column names to create the XML element names. When you concat two values together `','+ NAME` the resulting column has no name so `FOR XML PATH` can not generate an element name for you.

The behavior is documented in [Columns without a Name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510469(v=sql.110).aspx).

> Any column without a name will be inlined. For example, computed
>   columns or nested scalar queries that do not specify column alias will
>   generate columns without any name.

Comment: This is one of the most important things I've read regarding this. This proves that the code is actually a hack and probably can't be relied on in future releases. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   alias the column - then you get xml tags
```

do not alias the column - then no xml tags

-- with tags

select 'apple' apple for xml path('')

-- without tags

select 'apple' for xml path('')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).